# HtmlAgilityPack - Select td Attribute from Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get the author name from this [site](http://libgen.io/foreignfiction/index.php?last=&f_ext=&f_lang=All) .. The site simply shows a result of 25 Rows .. Each row contain different info like authors name, Title ...etc

I tried lots of solution to select the author name for each tr .. but failed to retrieve the author name .. Here is my code if someone can help me to know what i missed!

```
var documentx = new HtmlWeb().Load(post.ExtLink);
        var div = documentx.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*//table[2]//tr");
        if (div != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in div)
            {
                Book model = new Book();
                var author= item.SelectSingleNode("//td[1]//a").InnerText.ToString();

                //var title = item.SelectNodes("//td").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
                //var img = item.Descendants("img").Select(a1 => a1.GetAttributeValue("src", null)).FirstOrDefault();

                model.Book_Description = author;

            }
        }
```

I want to get the author name for each row this photo explain exactly what i want:

[image]

I tried to debug the code .. and it's doing well before the foreach it shows that it has a 25 row result then when foreach start executing it's not showing the expected result or value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
   var div = documentx.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*//table[3]//tr");
```

instead of:

```
    var div = documentx.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*//table[2]//tr");
```

and use it like this:

```
var author = item.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
var series = item.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
var title = item.ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying .. Actually the author get a value right now .. but title not! do you know why? ... and table[2] is working in this case not 3

Comment: it works good on my end. Author, series and title are taken as they are on the website.